# Desktop doesn't start after upgrade to Ubuntu 20

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 20.04, desktop-environments, lvm

I've a dual boot ( windows + ubuntu ) with grub2.

I had Ubuntu 16 and I upgraded it via UI ( I was informed about some crashes about packages it couldn't get, but the process continued until the very end ).

After this, windows works normally but UI doesn't start showing the following message:

`ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory`

I guess that's all information I have.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I have all terminals working ( ctrl+alt+f2-7 ), desktop does not start and I just got the line I mentioned above ( log referring to lvm2 ) and the blinking caret. If I switch between tty's like a crazy man, sometimes, when I go to the desktop one, desktop appears for a fraction of a second.

My GPU is XFX RX 5500 XT Thicc II Pro.